Scrambling Time in Black Holes
Peter Shor argues that the scrambling time for a black hole—defined as the time it takes for information to be thoroughly mixed across the event horizon—scales as $\mathcal{O}(M^2)$, where M is the mass of the black hole.
Shor's argument is based on modeling the black hole's photon sphere as being divided into cells, each of which is a small region through which information must propagate. Given the causal constraints of general relativity (where information cannot travel faster than the speed of light), Shor suggests that the information must be transmitted sequentially from one cell to the next. Since the number of cells scales as $M^2$, and the time to traverse each cell scales as M, the total scrambling time is then $\mathcal{O}(M^2)$.
How exactly does this cell structure work within the photon sphere?

I'm not sure what you mean by structure. The photon sphere is just a sphere, although I suppose it is a bit unusual because all of its geodesics are light-like.

FWIW, the Schwarzschild radial coordinate is defined in terms of the concentric spheres: they have circumference $2\pi r$ and area $4\pi r^2$, as measured by a local observer (in freefall).

Maybe reading the original paper would be helpful :)
